# MSMQ max count message notification

Tags: windows-services, msmq

We are in process of implementing [msmq](/questions/tagged/msmq) for the quick storage of the messages and process them in disconnected mode. Typical usage of any message broker.

One of the administration requirement is to send the automatic notification to administrator/developers if the queue messages (unprocessed) count reaches 1000.

- Can it be done out of the box? If yes then how?
- If no then do I need to write some windows service (or any sort of scheduler) to check the count every x-seconds?

Any suggestions or past experience is welcome..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only (partially) built-in solution would be to set up the *MSMQ Queue* [performance counter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc771098(v=ws.10).aspx) which gives you this information for private queues on the server.

There are a number of other solutions, including a [SCOM management pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36775), and some third party solutions like [evtools](http://evtools.net/msmq-monitor/), or you could roll you own using [System.Messaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.aspx).

Hope this is of help.

Answer (score 0):

There's commercial solution for this - [QueueMonitor](http://cogin.com/QueueMonitor/).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that software.

Edit

Few tips for this scenario:

- set message's `UseDeadLetterQueue` to true - this way if there's any issue with delivering messages at least they won't be lost but moved to system's dead letter queue.
- set message's `Recoverable` property to true - it does reduce performance, but for this kind of long running scenario there's too much risk that some restart or failure would loose messages which are only stored in memory.
- if messages are no longer valid after some period, you can use `TimeToReachQueue` to automatically delete them.

Comment: Link points to a utility so there's not much to copy here. However I realized I could provide few more tips for OPs scenario and edited answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank-you Dejan for improving your post.  I actually meant summarising the fine _tool_ but what you have done is even better. :)